# KDE development in Kubuntu

Tags: kde, development, kubuntu

I'm interested in developing for the KDE project, but I'm not sure what development environment or toolchain to use.

Which toolchain is recommended for KDE-focused development?

Comment: Though I'm not sure, you may take a look at [this](http://www.kde.org/applications/development/) and [this](http://www.kde.org/developerplatform/) pages...

Answer (score 1):

[KDevelop](http://kdevelop.org) is a good choice. You can also have a look at [Qt Creator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools). If you want something lighter, have a look at [Kate](http://kate-editor.org/).

There is no mandatory development environment though: many KDE developers also use Vim, Emacs or XEmacs for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question, and I'm sure the KDE community would love to have help.  I'd suggest looking on the kde.org website.
bertmanphx

Answer (score 0):

KDevelop is a quality IDE, with built-in support for KDE/Qt projects.

http://kdevelop.org/